# Can I force dovecot to ignore pop3 requests to delete received email?

Tags: dovecot, pop3

this is my first SF question, so please be gentile:

**Is there an easy way to force dovecot pop3 server to ignore "delete messages" commands after being fetched by the MUA?**

Here are the issues I'm facing:

- my boss wants to force everyone into a server-side "no delete
  message"-policy, for archiving, auditing and backup&recovery purposes
- the requisite here is pop3, so imap is out
- the mailusers are virtual users (held in a mysql db)
- don't have the budget to set up a separate mail-arvhing server
- don't want to use shaggy way (aka immutable flag, r/w permissions for Maildirs, etc)

One way to solve it (my guess) is to setup a postfix-forwarding rule to a separate MANAGER account, but there will be problems later in effective email recovering (aka clearly disseminate emails for different users)

Help?
Thanks!

Edit:
Will be asking same question on dovecot-dedicated forums, just thinking to broaden my tech scope :)
dovecot 2.0.15

Comment: This question is probably better asked over at the dovecot-users mailing list: <http://dovecot.org/mailinglists.html>. You also fail to specify which Dovecot version you are using. There are many differences between the various versions, some of them quite drastic.

Comment: Make a copy of every incoming mail in the MTA/MDA. Then you can comply to the policy, and users will be able to digest their emails.

Comment: Don't do pop3 deployments today. Use IMAP. And set up a sane archival solution.

Answer (score 6):

**Shortest answer**

No

**Short answer**

Get sources of dovecot, grok code edit and remove DELE command. Compile, install and be ready to "upgrade nightmare"

**Longer anser**

NEVER ignore and violate RFC, according to which DELE in POP3-session must delete message in spool. Tell boss to fund technical solution, because it give in future alot less headache and problems

**Solution for you task, not answer on question**

Change MTA configuration and extend every mail-user on host into "dual-user" alias-system, i.e. ordinary user@yourdomain.com will transform into something like

```
user: user-m, user-b
```

there user-m & user-b are identical users (for MTA and Dovecot) with one difference: user-m have POP3-access, user-b have not.

You have to have *2 space for mail, but get *manageable* and *full* archives per user

Answer (score 1):

While I know this is an old question, I'm updating it with current information.

The file:

```
/etc/dovecot/config.d/20-pop3.conf
```

contains the following section:

```
# This option changes POP3 behavior so that it's not possible to actually
# delete mails via POP3, only hide them from future POP3 sessions. The mails
# will still be counted towards user's quota until actually deleted via IMAP.
# Use e.g. "$POP3Deleted" as the value (it will be visible as IMAP keyword).
# Make sure you can legally archive mails before enabling this setting.
#pop3_deleted_flag =
```

So by enabling this with something like

```
pop3_deleted_flag = $$Pop3Deleted
```

Would achieve the required effect. (`$` is a special character in dovecot config, so double it to escape)

Comment: While trying this I got below error `doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-pop3.conf line 66: Unknown variable: $POP3Deleted`